# How to go from one index to another specific index in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know in Python you can go from one index to another specific index (ex. [0:7]). How might I do that in Javascript? The code below shows my attempt at going from index 0 to index 7, but it did not work.

```js
function sampleFunction(a, b, c) {
    a = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for (b = 0; b < a.length; b++) {
        c = a[b].innerHTML;
        if (c) {
            console.log(c[0, 7]);
        }
    }
}
```

- I am aware this might not follow proper Javascript "protocol" but just needed to produce an example of what I did.

Comment: Please give some more details on what the problem is, do you always what to jump from 0 to 7, or do you want to jump from a given index idx to an index idx+7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to slice an array for specific start and end index like python. In this case, you can use array slice function as follow,

```js
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

// .slice(start,end), Noted that end index is not inclusive
// to make end index inclusive +1 to end index
console.log(arr.slice(0,3))
```

For more information of slice function, please refer https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp